# Javascript get Blob with Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

i'm trying to receive data from websocket using JS and VUE and i have problem:

To receive data i'm using code:

```
created() {
console.log('Starting Connection to WebSocket')
this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/live')
// this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org')
this.connection.onopen = function (event) {
  console.log(event)
  console.log('Success')
}
this.connection.onmessage = webSocketOnMSG
 },
```

and trying to parse blob:

```
 function webSocketOnMSG(msg) {
  if (typeof (msg.data) === 'string') {
    jsonMSG(msg.data)
    return
  }
  bytes = new Uint8Array(msg.data)
  console.log('!!!BYTE', bytes)
  type = bytes[0]
  switch (type) {

  }
}
```

and `console.log('!!!BYTE', bytes)`

shows:

```
Blob {size: 187086, type: ""}
```

but it should be:

```
ArrayBuffer(187086)
```

and because of it `type` is undefined.

But i have other (clear js version) not VUE and there it works fine.

Can you help me, whats wrong?

Comment: In your code, you're mixing `this.msg` and `msg`. Which is it? Also, there seem to be several variables used in the code that are never declared.

Comment: *"and `console.log('!!!BYTE', bytes)` shows: `Blob {size: 187086, type: ""}`"* All due respect, I find that very hard to believe. The return value of `new Uint8Array` is **never** a `Blob`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `msg.data` really is a blob, you'd use the blob's [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method to read that blob into an `ArrayBuffer`, and then make a `Uint8Array` from that buffer. Note that `arrayBuffer` returns a *promise*; reading the blob content is an asynchronous operation.

Example:

```
function webSocketOnMSG(msg) {
    if (typeof msg.data === "string") { // `typeof` isn't a function, no need for `()`
        jsonMSG(msg.data);
        return;
    }
    // Assuming `msg.data` really is a `Blob`, then:
    msg.data.arrayBuffer()
    .then(buf => new Uint8Array(buf))
    .then(bytes => {
        console.log('!!!BYTE', bytes);
        const type = bytes[0];
        switch (type) {
            // ...
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly is the "Promise"?

Comment: @Ilkar - I don't know what you're asking there. If you're asking what a promise is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise